# Regarding the use of tf.tile?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am trying to get the numpy code into tensorflow. But when I run the session I am getting the below error.

Here is the code:

```
def cal_anchors():
    # Output:
    #   anchors: (w, l, 2, 7) x y z h w l r
    x = np.linspace(0,48,240) #48/.2
    y = np.linspace(20,-20,200) #40/.2
    cx, cy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    # all is (w, l, 2)
    cx = np.tile(cx[..., np.newaxis], 2)
    cy = np.tile(cy[..., np.newaxis], 2)
    cz = np.ones_like(cx) * (-1.465)       
    w = np.ones_like(cx) *   0.6          
    l = np.ones_like(cx) * 0.8 
    h = np.ones_like(cx) * 1.73  
    r = np.ones_like(cx)  #(200,240,2)
    print(r.shape)
    r[..., 0] = 0  # 0   #(200,240,1)
    r[..., 1] = 90 / 180 * np.pi  # 90

    # 7*(w,l,2) -> (w, l, 2, 7)
    anchors = np.stack([cx, cy, cz, h, w, l, r], axis=-1)

    return anchors
    
print(cal_anchors().shape)  #(200,240,2,7)
```

#tensorflow code

```
def anchors():
    
    x = tf.linspace(0.0,48.0,240)
    y = tf.linspace(-20.0,20.0,200)
    cx,cy = tf.meshgrid(x,y)
    cx = tf.expand_dims(cx,2)
    cy = tf.expand_dims(cy,2)
    cx = tf.tile(cx,2)
    cy = tf.tile(cy,2)
    cz = tf.ones_like(cx)
    w = tf.ones_like(cx)
    l = tf.ones_like(cx)
    h = tf.ones_like(cx)
    r = ones_like(cx)
    r[:,:,0] = 0
    pi = tf.constant(3.141592)
    r[:,:,1] = tf.math.divide(90,tf.math.multiply(180,pi))

    anchros = tf.stack([cx,cy,cz,h,w,l,r],axis=-1,name="anchors")
    
    sess = tf.Session()
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    result = sess.run(anchros)
    print(result.shape)

anchors()
```

I am getting the below error:

```
File "anchros.py", line 39, in anchors
cx = tf.tile(cx,2)
File "/home/surendra/venv/tensorflow2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 11450, in tile
        _ops.raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
      File "/home/surendra/venv/tensorflow2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 6862, in raise_from_not_ok_status
        six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
```

File "", line 3, in raise_from

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Expected multiples to be 1-D, but got shape [] [Op:Tile]
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: please post the complete error report starting with traceback. You can surround the report with 3` before and 3` after to properly format the output.

Comment: @itprorh66 I updated the full error messgae

Comment: Instead of expanding the dims you need to flatten it to a 1d array use `cx = tf.reshape(cx,-1)`

Comment: Please check the docs: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tile The `multiples` argument cannot be a number, it has to be a list (in the 1D case, a list with a single entry).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of issues there, this should work:

```
def anchors():
    x = tf.linspace(0.0, 48.0, 240)
    y = tf.linspace(-20.0, 20.0, 200)
    cx, cy = tf.meshgrid(x, y)
    cx = tf.expand_dims(cx, 2)
    cy = tf.expand_dims(cy, 2)
    cx = tf.tile(cx, [1,1,2])
    cy = tf.tile(cy, [1,1,2])
    cz = tf.ones_like(cx)
    w = tf.ones_like(cx)
    l = tf.ones_like(cx)
    h = tf.ones_like(cx)
    r = tf.Variable(initial_value=tf.ones_like(cx))
    r[:, :, 0].assign(tf.zeros(r.shape[:2]))
    pi = tf.constant(3.141592)
    r[:, :, 1].assign(tf.multiply(tf.math.divide(90., tf.math.multiply(180., pi)), tf.ones(r.shape[:2])))

    anchros = tf.stack([cx, cy, cz, h, w, l, r], axis=-1, name="anchors")

    sess = tf.Session()
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    result = sess.run(anchros)
    print(result.shape)
```